# Ignore all punctuation from user input C#

Tags: c#

How do I remove all punctuation characters from user input? I have a string variable which holds the input, but the input can also look like this:

```
string line = " :%tgc_7_$;:U|F]wyWhb3230;n7"`da ";
```

So obviously the quotes are messing with the whole code. I've tried this

```
 var sb = new StringBuilder();

 foreach (char c in line)
 {
     if (!char.IsPunctuation(c))
         sb.Append(c);
 }

 line = sb.ToString();
```

But that doesn't solve the quote thing for example. Thank you for all advice given.

EDIT - I want to extract just numbers out of it, I have the code, but I need a string without quotes "" and = because when it appears  I get an error

Comment: You mean the back-tick (`) character? Back-ticks are "symbols" in Unicode, not punctuation.  So all you want is digits and characters?

Comment: why do you say the quotes are messing with the whole code. I suspect more than the double quotes satisfy IsPunctuation()

Comment: If the double quote is messing with your code then have you tried escaping it? Ex: `string line = "blah\"blah"`.

Comment: the thing is I dont know where " character will appear or where = will appear. All I know is I will have a string full of random characters and I want to remove all punctuation so I can later extract numbers out of it

Comment: @Crash  `I want to remove all punctuation so I can later extract numbers out of it ` ==>  http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Eser Okay sorry, didnt know it was important, because I thought that what I wrote is enough. However it is a task, where you are given 20 test strings and you should write a code, which extracts all numbers out of it. So far I managed to write the extraction part, but Im struggling with string containing special characters like "" == etc. My idea is, first remove all special characters or punctuation, leave numbers or letters, second extract the numbers out of it.

Comment: Well...there's Char.IsLetterOrDigit( c )

Comment: @Crash What is the expected output from `12..34`? `12` and `34` or `1234`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve something you want based off the comments and your edits, just simply change.

```
 var sb = new StringBuilder();

 foreach (char c in line)
 {
     if (char.IsDigit(c))
         sb.Append(c);
 }

 line = sb.ToString();
```

line should then have just numbers after this.

Comment: FYI: Your code can be reduced to a one-liner `line = string.Concat(line.Where(char.IsDigit));`

Comment: Oh yes, I was aware of that.  I was just tying it to what was provided in the question so they could see the difference in what they wrote with what I wrote.  If they want to refactor it, let them.